# how to melt the dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R,which is the result of time series forecasting

```
       Jun      Jul      Aug
1 2616.540 2616.363 2388.369
```

I want this dataframe in below format

```
   Month
1  2616.54
2  2616.36
3  2388.36
```

I tried with `melt` but it does not give me expected output.

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: Dataframe in expected format as mentioned above.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread. I thought you already got that and did not like it. :)

Comment: can you show the code that you tried with melt?

Comment: Why not use `t(df)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating some data to work with:

```
tim <- data.frame(2616, 2617, 2388)
colnames(tim) <- c("Jun", "Jul", "Aug")
```

This is our data `tim`:

```
   Jun  Jul  Aug
1 2616 2617 2388
```

You can use the `melt` function and then select only the column you wish to keep. The following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
melt(tim, value.name = "Month") %>% select(Month)
```

Produces:

```
  Month
1  2616
2  2617
3  2388
```

Alternatively, without using `dplyr`:

```
melt(tim, value.name = "Month")[2]
```

Produces exactly the same output too:

```
  Month
1  2616
2  2617
3  2388
```

If there is no need to use `melt()`, base R's transpose function works just as well, if not more efficient:

```
t(tim)
    [,1]
Jun 2616
Jul 2617
Aug 2388
```

Comment: When I run above script it gives me following error `Using Jun, Jul, Aug as id variables
Error in inds_combine(.vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n`

Comment: Did you use the `melt()` function from `reshape2` package?

Comment: Yes,I used exactly same package

Comment: This is how my dataframe is getting created `df<- data.frame(forecast(xgb_fourier,nrow(test_data)))`

Comment: Can you call  `dput(df)` and paste the resulting structure here?

Comment: Got it. it was factor I converted it into numeric and it works fine now. Thanks aton

Answer (score 4):

There is really no need for `melt` or any additional R package. Base R's `stack` suffices

```
stack(df)[, -2, drop = F]
#    values
#1 2616.540
#2 2616.363
#3 2388.369
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
melt(DF, value.name = "Month")[c("Month")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(dat <- ts(c(2616.540, 2616.363, 2388.369), frequency = 12))
#       Jan      Feb      Mar
#1 2616.540 2616.363 2388.369

data.frame(Month = dat)
#      Month
# 1 2616.540
# 2 2616.363
# 3 2388.369
```

As you see, I assume you're data is of class `ts`.

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `unlist` from `base R` and convert it to a `data.frame`

```
data.frame(Month = unlist(df, use.names = FALSE))
#   Month
#1 2616.540
#2 2616.363
#3 2388.369
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Jun = 2616.54, Jul = 2616.363, Aug = 2388.369), 
 .Names = c("Jun", 
 "Jul", "Aug"), class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```